# List<image> exception "Parameter is not valid."

Tags: c#, image, list

I have problem with `List<Image>`

```
    List<Image> _Images = new List<Image>();
    int currIndex = 0;

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dialog.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) 
                return;
            _Images.Add(Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName));
            currIndex = _Images.Count - 1;
            picBox.Image = _Images[currIndex];
        }
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currIndex + 1 >= _Images.Count)
            return;
        picBox.Image = _Images[++currIndex];
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currIndex - 1 < 0)
            return;
        picBox.Image = _Images[--currIndex]; 
    }
```

After i added two images to that list, i got this exception when i press on Back button `btnBack_Click` : `Parameter is not valid.`
why did it work when i first add the image `picBox.Image = _Images[currIndex];` then when i try to get an image from index later, it gives me that exception?

**Note:** i didn't use ImageList, because as i know, it has ImageSize which will be constant for all images.

so how would i get it work?

**Update :**

It worked now, when i changed `List<Image>` to `List<Stream>`

```
picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(_Images[--currIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `List<Image>` to `List<Stream>`

```
picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(_Images[--currIndex]);
```

Then it will work.